# c++ class& className

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I'm trying to expand my knowledge in c++ and was trying to figure out the following function in openFrameworks for collision detection and notice some particular weird pattern that I have never seen before, here is the code:

```
    void addForce(float targetX, float targetY, float radius, float scale) {
    std::deque<Tree*> toProcess;
    toProcess.push_back(this);
    float xd, yd, length, effect;
    float sqradius = radius * radius;
    while(!toProcess.empty()) {
        Tree& curTree = *(toProcess.front());
        toProcess.pop_front();
        if(targetX > curTree.minX - radius && targetX < curTree.maxX + radius &&
           targetY > curTree.minY - radius && targetY < curTree.maxY + radius) {
            if(curTree.nParticles) {
                for(int i = 0; i < curTree.nParticles; i++) {
                    Particle& curParticle = *(curTree.particles[i]); //IS IT PASSING A REFERENCE TO A POINTER OF A METHOD CALLED .particles[i]????????
                    xd = curParticle.x - targetX;
                    yd = curParticle.y - targetY;
                    if(xd != 0 && yd != 0) {
                        length = xd * xd + yd * yd;
                        if(length < sqradius) {
                            length = sqrtf(length);
                            xd /= length;
                            yd /= length;
                            effect = 1 - (length / radius);
                            effect *= scale;
                            curParticle.xf += effect * xd;
                            curParticle.yf += effect * yd;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if(curTree.hasChildren) {
                toProcess.push_back(curTree.nw);
                toProcess.push_back(curTree.ne);
                toProcess.push_back(curTree.sw);
                toProcess.push_back(curTree.se);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the following line:

```
Particle& curParticle = *(curTree.particles[i]);
```

Passing a reference(?) to a pointer of a class(?).

You can also see it here:

```
Tree& curTree = *(toProcess.front());
```

Is here dereferencing curTree to the front of the deque(?)

If some C++ guru can explain this to me I will really appreciate. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `curTree.particles[i]` is a pointer to some object. `*(curTree.particles[i])` is that object itself. `curParticle` is made to refer to - to name, to alias - that object, so that it could be conveniently referred to later.

Comment: Similarly, `toProcess.front()` is an element at the front of `toProcess` queue. Apparently, it's a pointer to some object. `*(toProcess.front())` is that object. `curTree` is made to refer to that object.

Comment: That makes sense and I partially get it. What I don't get is why is he using a "&" reference would it be the same as using Tree* curParticle = (curTree.particles[i]) and so to say Tree& curTree = *(toProcess.front()) ?? Pointer instead of reference?

Comment: @mauricioSanchez Using a reference or a pointer is not the same thing. References must be initialized, and cannot be changed to refer to another object later, and free you from the hassle of using the dereferencing operator to access the referenced object. The important point to keep in mind is that by reading the code you know that the reference is always bound to the same object - the one with which it was initialized. With a pointer, you never know. You can see it as a useful code documentation strategy if you'd like.

Comment: @Filipe Gonçalves that being said, is the reference on Tree& curTree = *(toProcess.front()); pointing specifically at the first element in that deque?

Comment: There's not much fundamental difference between pointers and references. It's largely syntactic sugar. Yes, you could write `Tree* curTree = toProcess.front();`, then replace all `curTree.someField` with `curTree->someField`. The meaning of this program will remain unchanged; the appearance will arguably become a bit uglier.

Comment: @mauricioSanchez it is pointing to whatever `toProcess.front()` returns. Given its name, yes, I would say it's pointing to the first element in the deque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to look at the object declaration to answer your question:

```
std::deque<Tree*> toProcess;
```

So, `toProcess` is a deque of pointers. Now, see the documentation for `front()` : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/front

The member function returns a reference to the first item. In your case it is a reference to a pointer to `Tree` which can copied into the container's `value_type`. See the docs for typedefs/aliases defined by `deque`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque

In C++98:

```
Tree *front = toProcess.front();
```

In C++11:

```
auto front  = toProcess.front();
```

Notes:

- the stack variable contains a pointer in either case
- the value of the pointer is copied from the reference to a pointer
- it is cheap (and common) to copy pointers as they occupy a machine register